# How to control starting point in tikz, automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata, chain

I am trying to create the Markov chain. And at the first sreenshot you can see what I get now. It is horrible that arrows intersect the second ellipse in the first line.

I want to fix it by changing a starting position of all these arrows. I want something as shown on my picture. But in automata all arrows move from the center of state and I worry that it is impossible.

My tryings are nothing. Nothing helps me. Sorry, if it is a duplicate.

[image]

My wish:

[image]

MWE:

```
    %document information
\documentclass[a5paper,openany,9pt]{extbook} %главы начинаются с любой страницы

\usepackage{tikz}   

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata,}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{elliptic state/.style={draw,ellipse}}
\node[elliptic state]              (20) {\footnotesize i-1,0};
\node[elliptic state, right=of 20]              (21) {\footnotesize i-1,1};

\node[elliptic state,below=of 20]      (30) {\footnotesize i,0};
\node[elliptic state,right=of 30]      (31) {\footnotesize i,1};
\node[elliptic state,right=of 31]      (32) {\footnotesize i,2};
\node[elliptic state,right=of 32,draw=none]      (33) {\vphantom{{\vphantom{\footnotesize i-1,0}}}\ldots};
\node[elliptic state,right=of 33]      (34) {\footnotesize i,$W_i-2$};
\node[elliptic state,right=of 34]      (35) {\footnotesize i,$W_i-1$};
\draw[
    >=latex,
%   every node/.style={above,midway},% either
auto=right,                      % or
every loop,
]

 (21)  edge               node {1} (20)
 (20)  edge[bend right=-5] node[pos=0.8, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (35)   
 (20)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (34)
 (20)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (32)     
 (20)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (31)
 (20)  edge           node[pos=0.5, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (30);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a specific anchor of the `20` node, e.g.

```
\draw[
    >=latex,
%   every node/.style={above,midway},% either
auto=right,                      % or
every loop,
]
 (21)  edge               node {1} (20)
 (20.south)  edge[bend right=-5] node[pos=0.8, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (35)   
 (20.south)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (34)
 (20.south)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (32)     
 (20.south)  edge           node[pos=0.75, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (31)
 (20.south)  edge           node[pos=0.5, sloped, above] {$p/W_i$}   (30);
```

This way all the `edge`s will start from the `south` anchor, i.e. the bottom of the node. You can also use an angle instead of a named anchor, e.g. `20.290`.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. It works. I have not noticed this in manual. :-(

Comment: @Dida Well, the manual is rather large. As far as I can see, node anchors are first discussed in the first of the tutorials (in the section on adding text), and drawing lines to anchors are discussed in the second tutorial (in the section on connecting nodes).